# How to write express req object to file?

Tags: node.js, json, express, http-post, fs

So I'm wanting to grab some data about the user from the req object but when consoling it out the terminal doesn't show the entire object.

I have tried a few solutions the writing the file part seems to work when using the fs = require('fs') but I cannot stringify the request object as the file only shows [object, object] when writing to the file.

the code below shows how I'm trying to save to the file

```js
router.get("/:shortUrl", async (req, res) => {
  const result = JSON.stringify(req);
  console.log(result)

  fs.writeFile("result.txt", result, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File successfully written to disk');
  }); 
});
```

The error I'm receiving out of the JSON.stringify looks like so.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: Even if you could, it does you no good to write a `req` object out to disk.  It contains lots of stuff that can't be represented on disk and is temporal, including sockets, state for this particular http request and so on and it has circular data structures which can't be converted to JSON anyway.  So, instead, you need to concentrate on writing only certain properties from that object to disk.  Exactly what are you trying to save to disk and for what purpose?  You should probably create your own object, set properties on it, convert to JSON and write that JSON to disk.

Comment: I was trying to access data regarding the origin of the request ie the browser it was made from the ip address of the client ect for analytics im currently building on who is requesting what, but i wasnt entirely sure what was in the req object so was trying to print it all to a file.

Comment: This is what the debugger is for.  Set a breakpoint, examine the entire object and see everything in it.  I'd suggest you learn how to use the nodejs debugger - it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

So it seems to be down to the circular json the below example should help anyone out that's also coming across this issue. Its a helper function that decycles the object to make it stringifyable.

```js
  function decycle(obj, stack = []) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object')
        return obj;

    if (stack.includes(obj))
        return null;

    let s = stack.concat([obj]);

    return Array.isArray(obj)
        ? obj.map(x => decycle(x, s))
        : Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(obj)
                .map(([k, v]) => [k, decycle(v, s)]));
  }

  const result = JSON.stringify(decycle(req));

  fs.writeFile("result.txt", result, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File successfully written to disk');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using express method provides you with request object params.

So instead writting whole object you can access that object params and write to the .txt file

```
router.get("/:shortUrl", async (req, res) => {

    const result = req.params.shortUrl;

    console.log(result)

    fs.writeFile("result.txt", result, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
      console.log('File successfully written to disk');
    }); 
 });
```

I doubt that you need whole object.

Comment: It's not that I need the whole object I was just trying to see what you could make use of from a data-gathering exercise for analytics data. Turns out it didn't contain what I was really after anyway could only really see the browser it was originating from which inturn was useful but not what I was wanting.